# Location of vcruntime140.dll (installed with Visual C++ Redistributable 2015)

Tags: windows, dll, visual-c++-runtime

I'd like to ship the dll with the binary, so that the users don't have to install Visual C++ Redistributable.

But I can't find the location of vcruntime140.dll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it:

`C:/Windows/SysWOW64/vcruntime140.dll`

Comment: Only in "SysWOW64" if your process is 32 bit. If it's 64 bit, the one you seek is under `c:\windows\system32`